# Appending TR to Table using pure JavaScript without id reference for table

Tags: javascript

I have a code as follows,

```
<?php

$actionbutton = '<input type="button" onclick="document.location.href=\'/backoffice_dev.php/currency/edit/EUR\';" value="Edit">';
$tr = '<tr><td>'.$addNewCurrencyPOST["id"].'</td>
<td><div class="led on"></div></td>
<td>'.$addNewCurrencyPOST["symbol"].'</td>
<td>'.$addNewCurrencyPOST["symbolhtml"].'</td>
<td>'.$addNewCurrencyPOST["usdrate"].'</td>
<td>'.$addNewCurrencyPOST["eurrate"].'</td>
<td>'.$actionbutton.'</td></tr>';

?>

<script>
    var tr = <?php echo $tr ?>;
</script>
```

I need to add the value coming in tr to a table which is already present, i'm preferably looking for a way to use this without `insertRow` and `insertCell`. But including these functions is also OK. Note that there is no id for the table, only class name will be available. Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you not want to use the methods designed to accomplish your goal? Incidentally, JavaScript works on HTML, not php.

Comment: @DavidThomas Not doing purposefully. But need to change my code in lot of places. that is the reason. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have:

```
<table id='mytable'>....</table>
```

You can

```
<script>
    var tr = <?php echo $tr ?>;
    var table=document.getElementById('mytable');
    table.innerHTML+=tr;
</script>
```

Edit:

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mHwTe/)

Comment: Is it possible only with class name?

Comment: that add a new tbody in the table each time you add a row, this maybe can fix it http://jsfiddle.net/DeedE/2/ (tried only in chrome)

Comment: @Udhayakumar you can use getElementsByClassName and loop for all the tables http://jsfiddle.net/DeedE/3/

Comment: @Udhayakumar sure, you can use `getElementsByClassName`, but have in mind that this will return an array of elements, so if you want to access the first you need to use `table[0]`. I'll go with id's because ids tend to be uniques and classes dont.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this in javascript:

```
tb = document.createElement("tbody")  
var tbody  = document.createElement('tbody'); 
table.appendChild(tbody);
var table_row  = document.createElement('tr');
tbody.appendChild(table_row)//
```